# Is there any way to share data among the tabs in TabBarView in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, project, dart-pub

I am a beginner student and trying to develop an app called Taskify. I have this need to share data among the tabs in the TabBarView property. So there are three tabs named, All Tasks - On Processed - Completed. I want to list the on processed tasks to its respective task and the same with the completed tasks. But can't find any way to deal with that.

This is my code for a Task Overview Card tab :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TaskOverviewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String taskName;
  final DateTime endTime;
  final DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

  TaskOverviewCard({super.key, required this.taskName, required this.endTime});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0, left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade300)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
          child: Column(children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                //TASK NAME
                Text(
                  taskName,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                //ICON - MORE HORIZONTAL
                const Icon(Icons.more_horiz)
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      //DEADLINE TIME
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(Icons.schedule, size: 16),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 6,
                          ),
                          Text(DateFormat.jm().format(endTime))
                        ],
                      ),
                      //COMPLETED OR NOT
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 6.0, vertical: 4.0),
                          child: currentTime.isAfter(endTime)
                              ? const TaskCompleted()
                              : const TaskInProgress(),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCompleted extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskCompleted({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Completed',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.check_circle,
          color: Colors.green,
          size: 15,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TaskInProgress extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskInProgress({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          'On Processing',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.run_circle,
          color: Colors.orange,
          size: 15,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is tab for all the tasks that are going to be listed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taskify/task_pages/task_utilities/task_overview_card.dart';

class AllTasks extends StatelessWidget {
  const AllTasks({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          TaskOverviewCard(
            taskName: 'Meeting about the previous task',
            endTime: DateTime(2023, 7, 23, 8, 00),
          ),
          TaskOverviewCard(
            taskName: 'Meeting with the client',
            endTime: DateTime(2023, 7, 23, 10, 00),
          ),
          TaskOverviewCard(
            taskName: 'Code the interface',
            endTime: DateTime(2023, 7, 23, 15, 00),
          ),
          //TaskOverviewCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should use a state management solution and keep the state in the widget tree at least one level higher than your tabs
check this documentation from flutter.dev:
https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options